# Delphi GetHostByName equivalent for firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, gethostbyname

Is there any GetHostByName equivalent for firemonkey, which works for Desktop Win32/Win64/Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Look into `System.Net.Socket` and you find `TIPAddress.LookupName` which has the implementation you are looking for. On Posix it calls `gethostbyname` from `Posix.NetDB`.

Comment: FYI, there has been a bug in `TIPAddress.LookupName`: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12829 It affects *Delphi 10 Seattle* and has been fixed in *Delphi 10.1 Seattle*.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann this is marked as resolved but actually still not fixed as of Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Answer (score 2):

If you use Indy, its cross-platform `TIdStack` interface has public `ResolveHost()` and `HostByName()` methods (where `ResolveHost()` calls `HostByName()` for input that is not already an IP address).  `HostByName()` internally uses either `getaddrinfo()` or `gethostbyname()`, depending on platform.

The caveat, however, is that such platform functions return a list of IP addresses that can have more than one IP in it, but `ResolveHost()`/`HostByName()` currently only return the first IP in the list.  If you needed the full list, you would have to drop down to the platform layer and call the socket functions directly.

Comment: thank you, I will definitely take a look at TIdStack, it seems to make things easier than my current solution.